# Matlab/R: Restructure data in R which was imported from Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, import

I have created a small dataset in matlab which looks like this 
[image]

and can be downloaded for a reproducible example here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2qssxd5pu0x6hn/TEST_DATA.mat?dl=0

What I would like to do is to import this dataset into R and restructure it. I found the `R.matlab` package to be helpful and tried the following.

```
   # Import matlab file into R
    library(R.matlab)
    # Read in data from matlab file
    data_m <- readMat('TEST_DATA.mat')
    # convert this to data.frame
    df <- as.data.frame(data_m)
```

What I get is the following data.frame:

```
df
                  TEST.DATA.1.1          TEST.DATA.2.1
ID                             2         4
YEAR            1990, 1991, 1992         2000, 2001
DATA      10, 20, 30, 71, 72, 73         55, 60, 0, 2, 4, 6
DATA.NAME                   Test         n1, n2, n3
```

As suggested by a comment here the output of `str(df)`

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ TEST.DATA.1.1:List of 4
  ..$ ID       : num [1, 1] 2
  ..$ YEAR     : num [1:3, 1] 1990 1991 1992
  ..$ DATA     : num [1:3, 1:2] 10 20 30 71 72 73
  ..$ DATA.NAME: chr [1, 1] "Test"
 $ TEST.DATA.2.1:List of 4
  ..$ ID       : num [1, 1] 4
  ..$ YEAR     : num [1:2, 1] 2000 2001
  ..$ DATA     : num [1:2, 1:3] 55 60 0 2 4 6
  ..$ DATA.NAME:List of 3
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] "n1"
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] "n2"
  .. ..$ :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] "n3"
```

How could I restructure `df` so that I get two different `data.frames` which are split by the `ID` field?

```
> ID2
  ID YEAR data.Test data.Test2
1  2 1990        10         71
2  2 1991        20         72
3  2 1992        30         73
> ID4
  ID YEAR data.n1 data.n2 data.n3
1  4 2000      55       0       4
2  4 2001      60       2       6
```

Comment: posting the result of `str(df)` could be helpful

Comment: I edited the question with the output of `str(df)`

Comment: try `df1 = df$TEST.DATA.1.1` and `df$TEST.DATA.2.1` as a start then `df1 = cbind(df1$YEAR, df1$DATA)` and finally `names(df1)=...`

Comment: It looks like you are missing `Test2` in the data structure sent from matlab.

Comment: @mts thanks for your suggestion. However I have about 400 different IDs in the data which should be split into several data.frames. This is just a shortened (hopefully) reproducible example....

Comment: @jed No this is correct. Test2 isn't given and I have to find a way how both cases can be treated (automatic extension from Test1 to Test2 and so on in one case and when stated n1, n2 and n3 also an automatic numeration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, not sure if there's a better way.

```
❥ data_m <- readMat('~/Downloads/TEST_DATA.mat')
❥ frame <- as.data.frame(data_m)
❥ first <- frame[,1]
❥ second <- frame[,2]
❥ f_clean <- data.frame(first$ID, first$YEAR, first$DATA)
❥ f_clean
  first.ID first.YEAR X1 X2
1        2       1990 10 71
2        2       1991 20 72
3        2       1992 30 73
❥ s_clean <- data.frame(second$ID, second$YEAR, second$DATA)
❥ s_clean
  second.ID second.YEAR X1 X2 X3
1         4        2000 55  0  4
2         4        2001 60  2  6
```

EDIT: Going off of @mts answer, we can do the following:

```
❥ f2 <- frame[!rownames(frame) %in% 'DATA.NAME',]
❥ sapply(f2, function(x) data.frame(x))
$TEST.DATA.1.1
  ID YEAR DATA.1 DATA.2
1  2 1990     10     71
2  2 1991     20     72
3  2 1992     30     73

$TEST.DATA.2.1
  ID YEAR DATA.1 DATA.2 DATA.3
1  4 2000     55      0      4
2  4 2001     60      2      6
```

Comment: as the OP has 400 IDs maybe loop through the last dimension of `frame` and store output in a list?